# Xpages: How to get only the first record of a categorised view

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, xpages-ssjs, domino-designer-eclipse

I'm doing a while loop to get records in a categorised view.
I want to return only the first record that meet the if condition and not the whole category.
The code below returns all the records in the category that passed the 'if' condition.

```
var vView:NotesView = database.getView("Document");
var doc:NotesDocument = vView.getFirstDocument();
while(doc != null){ 
  if(doc.getItemValueString("Status") == 'Live'){
      //get the first in the category here where condition is met
      var pVersion = doc.getItemValueString("Version");
      var pPro = doc.getItemValueString("Pro");
  }
  var tmpDoc:NotesDocument = vView.getNextDocument(doc);
  doc.recycle();
  doc = tmpDoc;
}
```

View below:

[image]

The arrow shows the records that I would like to return.

Comment: I think your code is extremely ineffective. Plan accordingly. Create a view with category combined from your condition. Then use NotesViewNavigator, traverse through categories only and get first document in every category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try breaking out of the loop once the doc is found:

```
var vView:NotesView = database.getView("Document");
var doc:NotesDocument = vView.getFirstDocument();
var done = false;
while(doc != null && !done){ 
  if(doc.getItemValueString("Status") == 'Live'){
      //get the first in the category here where condition is met
      var pVersion = doc.getItemValueString("Version");
      var pPro = doc.getItemValueString("Pro");
      done = true;
  }
  var tmpDoc:NotesDocument = vView.getNextDocument(doc);
  doc.recycle();
  doc = tmpDoc;
}
```

Comment: If it is the idea to keep doc when you go out of the loop, I would suggest to execute the last three commands only when done is false.

Answer (score 2):

Your graphic suggest you want the first document in each category that meets a condition?

For the question as asked:

```
var continueSearch = true
 while(doc != null && continueSearch) {
       if(...) {
            ...
            continueSearch = false;
        }
   ...
    }
```

That should do it

Answer (score 1):

Did you look at the notesviewnavigator class ?

Answer (score 0):

```
       var vView:NotesView = database.getView("Document");
       var doc:NotesDocument = vView.getFirstDocument();
       var product;
       while(doc != null){
            if(product != doc.getItemValueString("Product")){
              //get only the first in the category
              var pVersion = doc.getItemValueString("Version");
              var product = doc.getItemValueString("Product");
            }
       var tmpDoc:NotesDocument = vView.getNextDocument(doc);
       doc.recycle();
       doc = tmpDoc;
       }
```